# Unable to connect Socket Mobile scanner(Model: CHS 7Pi) in windows 10 uwp

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, socketmobile

I'm working in Socket Mobile scanner(Model:  CHS 7Pi) integration with Windows 10  UWP application. I'm getting following exception "Value does not fall within the expected range." after successfully making contact with scanner via bluetooth

I using below sample for my testing.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner

below msdn url suggest, it will support my scanner.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426649.aspx#Bluetooth

Issue recorder.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=89346CF5C45CEB8C!5726&authkey=!AAOPylWs7bEh39c&ithint=file%2czip

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue in debug mode with breackpoints. If you run example without breackpoints everything is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I fixed it. You should refer your product manual and scan barcode based on you platform to switch mode