# Does socket mobile SDK support Xamarin APP or Windows Universal APP?

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, socketmobile

Does socket mobile SDK support Windows Universal APP ?
I would like to use ScanAPI from Socket Mobile.

What about the XAMARIN support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does socket mobile SDK support Windows Universal APP

Probably not, there is no any documents or blogs talk about the support for Windows Runtime platform/UWP, although in the [ScanAPI document](http://www.socketmobile.com/docs/default-source/developer-documentation/scanapi.pdf?sfvrsn=2)

It mentioned **Windows Mobile**:

*The C# version uses a wrapper. `ScanAPI` has been compiled as a native (unmanaged) DLL. This DLL is ScanAPIDLL.dll for Windows platforms and ScanAPIDLLWM.dll for Windows Mobile platform. The managed API is assembled in ScanAPIManaged.dll for Windows platforms and in ScanAPIManagedWM.dll for the Windows Mobile platforms.*

**But it looks like this represents a family of mobile operating systems developed by Microsoft several years before instead of our *universal platform***：[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile)

> What about the XAMARIN support

Actually, the **Barcode Scanner** API has added support for several Models of Socket Mobile, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426649.aspx#Bluetooth)

[image]

There is a similar question about connecting Socket Mobile scanner in UWP app: [Unable to connect Socket Mobile scanner(Model: CHS 7Pi) in windows 10 uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268370/unable-to-connect-socket-mobile-scannermodel-chs-7pi-in-windows-10-uwp)

Comment: Yeah, I found I can use Microsoft POS for .NET (Bar code scanners are supported). Thanks for answer!

Comment: @Ania great, so is it the accepted answer for your question? :)